# nested try and except not working as expected

Tags: python, function, methods, try-except

I have a tkinter GUI with a login function that should pull up one of a number of different frames/toplevel widgets based on lines in a text file.

I used a nested try/except for the lower(else) portion of the function to check if certain lines exist in the text file, and what to do if they don't exist.
The problem is, if it executes the nested try, it also seemingly executes the nested except portion, pulling up two different Toplevel windows instead of one, and I'm not quite sure why its doing both...?

I've tried using the method when line 5 does not exist in the text file, and it executes the nested except just fine.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
    def login(self):
        global Users
        username = self.user_entry.get()
        pw = self.password_entry.get()
        run.Current_User.set(username)
        if (username, pw) in Users:
            #does some stuff irrelevant to the problem
            else:
                os.getcwd()
                os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Michael Sibille\\Desktop\\Duty Program Test Folder\\Employee Files')
                os.chdir(username)
                readfile = open('userdata.txt', 'r')
                lines = readfile.readlines()
                type = lines[2]
                #at this point, there are  5 lines (0-4) in the text file.
                try:
                    medical = lines[9]
                    if type.strip() == 'ADMIN':
                        main_window.switch_frame(self.master, Admin_Notebook)
                        self.after(500, self.destroy)
                        self.warn.config(text='Login Successful!', bg='lime green', justify='center')
                    else:
                        main_window.switch_frame(self.master, User_Notebook)
                        self.after(500, self.destroy)
                        self.warn.config(text='Login Successful!', bg='lime green', justify='center')
                except:
                    try:
                        contact = lines[5]
                        main_window.switch_frame(self.master, Create_Profile)
                        med = Medical(self.master)
                        self.after(500, self.destroy)
                        self.warn.config(text='Login Successful!', bg='lime green', justify='center')
                    except:
                        main_window.switch_frame(self.master, Create_Profile)
                        nameemailphone = Name_Email_Phone(self.master)
                        self.after(500, self.destroy)
                        self.warn.config(text='Login Successful!', bg='lime green', justify='center')
        else:
            self.warn.config(text="Invalid Username or Password", fg="black", bg='red', justify ='center')
```

Comment: In your comment you say that `lines` has 5 elements numbered 0-4, but you try to access lines[9] in the first try block and lines[5] in the second try block.  Also your indentation is messed up.  What does the function switch_frame do?

Comment: My thought process was, I want it to first check if line 9 exists, and if it doesn't, it would then check to see if line 5 existed. Did I go about that wrong? Should I have nested the try/except into the first try statement, instead of the except statement? Also, I don't see where indentation is messed up? 

switch_frame takes whatever frame is occupying the main tkinter window(main_window), destroys it and replaces it with a specified frame.

Comment: Maybe the only indentation problem is that first else, which isn't at the same level as the first if.  You stated that two windows get opened.  How do you know what code is resonsible tor doing that?  You know that both lines[5] and lines[9] don't exist (if your comment is correct) so both will raise an exception.  Therefore neither try block will execute.  The four lines in the second except block will run, and so something in those four lines *must* cause a second window to open (or else it's not caused by this code snippet).

Comment: Python has several debugging options (pydb and also IDLE).  You can insert print statements into the code to verify the execution path.

Comment: My bad- I accidentally deleted a nested if statement at the top trying to make the overall code shorter, so that's why that looks wrong. Also my bad, I said I have 0-4 lines in the text file, its actually 0-8 lines currently.  I'm testing to see that it executes the nested try statement by itself (switch_frame function, and med = Medical) Medical is one of the Toplevel windows. And the problem is, its pulling up the Medical Toplevel window and Also pulling up the Name_Email_Phone Toplevel window in the nested except at the same time... Sorry, I really fudged my initial explanation and question

Comment: Well...I'm embarrassed. As part of the __init__ method of the Create_Profile frame class, I added a line to also initialize the Name_Email_Phone Toplevel window... Thus, changing frames and pulling up Medical was pulling both up at the same time. Thanks for trying to make sense of my nonsense... I'm going to go stand in the corner now...

Comment: No problem - I'm glad you figured it out.